# Show 2 Definite Integrals are Equal

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $$I_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(2x)}\, dx$$ 
$$I_2=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(2x)}\,dx$$
Show that $I_1=I_2$.

I've managed to evaluate $I_1$ to be $0 \implies I_1=I_2=0$. However, I want to know how to show that the 2 definite integrals are equal without evaluating the integrals. I know there's some sort of symmetry going on.

Comment: Show each integrand is antisymmetric with respect to the center of the range of integration, $\pi/4$... and hence each integral vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $y = \pi/2 - x$. Then one arrives at
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{1 + \sin(2x)}\mathrm{d}x & = -\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - y\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - y\right)}{1 + \sin(\pi - 2y)}\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(y) - \cos(y)}{1 + \sin(2y)}\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = -\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(y) - \sin(y)}{1 + \sin(2y)}\mathrm{dy}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!